# Is there a translated / localized ISO 4217 currency code list?

Tags: localization, internationalization, translation, currency, currency-formatting

I am trying to find a localized / translated [ISO 4217 currency code list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217). What I found so far was only an English version of ISO 4217, but currency names like "Swiss Franc" have different translations per languages (as per https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q25344). Any lists or dbs out there that could be used inside an app without reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ISO 4217 standard](https://www.iso.org/standard/64758.html) defining the international currency codes seems to be provided by ISO only in English language. This is quite unusual, since many of the general purpose standards are provided by ISO in English, French and Russian.

Since currency codes per country evolve more quickly than standard committee can follow,  the maintenance of the standard was delegated to an agency that provides a [static list for free](https://www.iso.org/iso-4217-currency-codes.html), but also only in English. The European Publication Office provides the [list of currencies](https://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-5000700.htm) on a page that is translated in the 24 official languages of the European Union. There are a couple of other websites, not to speak of wikipedia, which also provide some more translations.

But before you start to develop a web-scraping app to get all the translations across all the known public sources, maybe you could just have a look at [**this amazing GitHub repository**](https://github.com/umpirsky/currency-list), which provides the list in almost any language, and in a lot of different formats (I recently discovered this link on the wikipedia page that you referenced).